# PostgreSQL Table special uniqueness constraint

Tags: sql, postgresql, relational-database, unique-constraint

I have a Users table in my Postgres DB. Currently, there is a uniqueness constraint on email. There are two possible roles: employee or master and they can belong to only one organisation. Now, there is a new requirement to add a role "consultant". This role can be a part of multiple organisations i.e. the uniqueness constraint will now change to email+organisation_id.
However, I don't want any user with role "employee" or "master" to be a part of more than 1 organisation.

**Allow**: role::consultant can be a part of OrgABC, OrgDEF, ....

**Disallow**: role::employee/role::master can only be a part of OrgABC OR OrgDEF
User table:

| user_id | org_id | role (enum: employee, master, consultant) |
| --- | --- | --- |

Is there a way I can achieve this in the same Users table itself with some special constraint/conditions? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try two partial unique indexes:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON tab (organization_id, email) WHERE role = 'consultant';
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON tab (email) WHERE role IN ('employee', 'master');
```